# How to know numerically the last saved file name

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating and saving .ini files in Excel. The files need to follow a specific naming convention that increments by 1 each time a file is created. Not all the files will be created in Excel, some will be done in a separate program. Is there a way to read the saved files in their folder to know which number is next?

For example there are files named exampleFile1.ini through exampleFile63.ini. From Excel using VBA or other means can I see that exampleFile63.ini was the last file and name the next exampleFile64.ini?

Thank you. I'm very new if thats not obvious.

Comment: Are you after the number after the highest number?  Or the first unused number?  E.g. if files numbered 1, 2, 3, 5 and 6 existed, do you want to use 4 or 7?  And do you need to be able to handle the situation where the other program might be creating a file with the same number as you are currently creating at the same time as you?

Comment: You can use the `Dir` function or the `FileSystemObject` to build a list of all files in a folder/directory. Add whatever logic you need to sort/parse them and determine the last-used number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: put the names of the files present in the directory into an array. Sort the array. Increment +1 to last entry of array. This is the most viable aproach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will return the next available .INI file name:

```
Private Function GetNextFile() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim fileName As String

    For i = 1 To 1000
        ' Update Path and File Name prefix below to where your .INI files will be stored.
        fileName = "d:\path\exampleFile" & i & ".ini"

        If Dir(fileName) = "" Then
            GetNextFile = fileName
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Call it like this:

```
Dim NextIniFile As String
NextIniFile = GetNextFile()
```